# How can I take a snapshot of the last frame of a video?

Tags: export, image, video-sequence-editor, video

I have a video clip and I would like export the last frame for further processing with Gimp. How can I extract or take a snapshot of the last frame of a video?

I'm interested in solution on Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the frame you would like to save, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render (you can also press *Render image* in *Render* at the top of the window, or *Render* in *Properties > Render settings > Render*):

[image]

Then press <kbd>F3</kbd> to save the resulting image.

Note that this will take other strips into account.

Comment: I can't with mac ox when I press f12 i go to another desktop..

Comment: @GM You can change the shortcuts under *file > user preferences*.